# Total Energy of a signal

Tags: c++, math, signals

I have been given this equation to calculate the total energy of a signal:

```
Ex= ∑ n|x[n]|2
```

Which to me suggests that you square each of the blocks up, then get the sum of the whole entire block. I am wondering if the code/Algorithm I have written is accurate for this equation and I have done it the most efficient way.

```
double totalEnergy(vector<double> data, const int rows, const int cols)
{
vector<double> temp;
double energy = 0;

for(int i=0; (i < 2); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; (j < 2); j++)
    {
        temp.push_back( (data[i*2+j]*data[i*2+j]) );
    }
}

energy = accumulate (temp.begin(), temp.begin()+(rows*cols), 0);
return energy;
 }
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

vector<double> data;
data.push_back(4);
data.push_back(4);

data.push_back(4);
data.push_back(4);

totalEnergy(data, 2, 2);

 }
```

Result: 64

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated :)!

Comment: You should probably use `rows` and `cols` as the loop limits.

Comment: @DanielFischer - My bad.. Was meant to do that, but added 2 for testing purposes! The equation / algorithm look though?

Comment: Well, what is the point of the `temp` vector? Does `accumulate` use Kahan summation or something to reduce accumulation of floating point errors, or would simply adding the squares directly to `energy` have the same effect?

Comment: @DanielFischer: `accumulate` does not do anything fancy, it just sums the numbers in the order in which they are present. You are right in that the `temp` vector is useless, as is passing the vector by value in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly not the most efficient way to do this computation although I think the implementation is nearly correct: the multiplication by `n` somehow got lost, though. Since I can't see what the sum index and bounds are I'm not going to fix this but I'll reproduce the results of the implementation, just "better". There are two obvious points which can be improved:

1. The code doesn't make any use of being in a particular column or row. That is, it could as well just consider the input as a flat array whose size is actually known from the size of the input vector.
2. The function uses two temporary vectors (the one passed to the function and one inside the function). Creating a `std::vector<T>` needs to allocate memory which isn't a cheap operation.

As a first approximation, I would transform the input vector in-place and then accumulate the result:

```
double square(double value) {
    return value * value;
}

double totalEnergy(std::vector<double> data) {
    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), &square);
    return std::accumulate (data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
}
```

The function still make a copy of the data and modifies it. I don't like this. Oddly enough the operation you implemented is basically an inner product of a vector with itself, i.e., this yields the same result without creating an extra vector either:

```
double totalEnergy(std::vector<double> const& data) {
    return std::inner_product(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), 0);
}
```

Assuming this implements the correct formula (although I'm still suspicious of the `n` in the original formula), this is probably considerable faster. It seem to be more concise, too...

Comment: Thank you for your input, I really like your solution :)! Are you saying the equation is wrong for calculating the total energy of a signal? I got the equation by asking: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3377/calculating-the-total-energy-of-a-signal/3378#comment7074_3378 thanks

Comment: No, I'm **not** saying that the equation is wrong! However, both your and my code don't implement this equation. In both cases the `n` is ignored. Looking at the source you pointed to, however, shows that `n` is the running index, i.e., this is what we implemented. Are the elements meant to be complex numbers? Otherwise I can't see any reason for using the absolute...

Comment: No complex numbers are used. By the n do you mean "[n]" wouldn't this be each of the blocks? Is there a way I can test it in Matlab?

Comment: The `n` I meant is in you formula which looks like "sum of n times square of absolute of E[n]": it is quite common in math to leave off the boundaries and the symbol when it is clear from the context what is meant. To do so `n` is conentionally the upper bound which made your formulation confusing to me. The article you pointed to shows a better version of the formula: we implemented that formula.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I know where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to remove the noise from a signal and I have discovered that "blocks" with low energy can be defined as noise.. The only problem here, is that I'm taking the whole signal, so, therefore, I couldn't possibly remove the noise. Instead, I need to split the vector into blocks, and then calculate the energy of each of the blocks and if it does not meet the threshold, the block get's removed from the vector. Thank you anyway :)!